# Dropzone.js - check filename length with accept

Tags: javascript, filenames, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone version 5.2. I've been searching for days on stackoverflow and other places trying to figure out how to implement this but it seems most related posts are about renaming/appending filenames which I don't wish to do. I simply want to reject a filename longer than 30 characters. I have the proper server-side validation for filename length included in my php upload file already, but I want to do a client-side check as well. The reason is that I don't want a client spending time uploading a file with a long filename to only THEN get an error after the upload. I've tried many things, but I think I am getting closer with the following (still not working though):

```
            accept: function(file, done) {
                if (filename.val().length > 30) {
                    done("Filename needs to be 30 characters max!");
                }
                else { done(); }
            },
```

I'd appreciate any assistance to be pointed towards the right path on this.

**EDIT: The solution turned out to be as listed in my own accepted answer**

Well after day 5 of trying to figure this out, I finally realized it was the following:

```
            accept: function(file, done) {
                if (file.name.length > 30) {
                    done("Filename exceeds 30 characters!");
                }
                else { done(); }
            },
```

I hope this helps anyone else trying to figure it out

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take at tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well after day 5 of trying to figure this out, I finally realized it was the following:

```
            accept: function(file, done) {
                if (file.name.length > 30) {
                    done("Filename exceeds 30 characters!");
                }
                else { done(); }
            },
```

I hope this helps anyone else trying to figure it out

Comment: I wondered what was `accept` callback because it is not described in [options page](https://docs.dropzone.dev/configuration/basics/configuration-options), but [the github README](https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone) says "src/options.js for all available options".  Now, I understand.  Thank you!.